# What is magenta shadow in anime and what does it mean?

Tags: trope, anime

*This question has haunted me for a long time! I was trying to search for anything I could find, but I have not found the answer.*

In anime, there are moments where the "camera" gets a weird purple border glow, usually on the bottom.

[image: Screenshot from anime "Gabriel Dropout", showing two main characters, one is smiling with a bit of smugness and the other is surprised, having comically large eyes showing realization of the situation]

Here's an example of what it looks like in *Gabriel DropOut* episode 4. In this case, it only appears on one character.

My best guess is that it represents some kind of emotions the characters have.

It could be that I don't have the right vocabulary and that's why I didn't find anything using search engines, but I'm really interested in the meaning behind this artistic choice.

Comment: Can you provide some more examples?

Comment: I bet they are related to / an extension of the similarly colored blush lines on that character's face. Based on this one frame only, my guess is that this character has just received some unexpected interpersonal validation (probably romantic, given the other toon's awkward surprise), and the magenta shadow confirms that this is uniquely important to her.